# Go to Display Button Factorytalk View ME?

Tags: plc, scada

I’m using Factor Talk View ME to program AB PanelView 1000 HMI and I can’t figure out how to program a button to activate “manual” mode and then goto a display directly after button is pushed. I can set them up individually with two separate buttons, but wasn’t sure if this can be done in one button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 types of buttons:

- For navigation
- For setting values (in plc or HMI tags). for your activated "manual" mode I guess?

I don't think you can do both with one button in ME(in FT View SE you can), however a solution can be to use a macro:

1 Create a new "Logic and control" => macro
2 Set your value in order to activate your "manual" mode
4 Create your button in order to display your screen
5 On your displayed screen, go to display setting => behaviour
6 Add your freshly created macro in Macro > startup field.

Is it what you expect ?